# PDF generated successfully but not showing as downloadable in the browser using ReactJS MySql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I I am struggling to download the pdf file in browser, i have created the pdf at back end and can see the file locally in back end and then i save it in the mysql (screenshot below) and after that using `API call` i retrieve the pdf document to be downloadable on browser but it is showing filename as [object object] and status `failed:no file` when trying to download.
I have looked around and see some places to convert pdf to base64 but i am not sure if i need it. any suggestions please.

**snippet** of `backend-Nodejs` code

1. **Backend**- sending file through API call

```
     let token = req.cookies.access_token;
     if (token) {
       let Invoice_No_Actual = req.body.invoice_Name;
// the below two res.set has been set now

     res.set("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + `${__dirname}\\` + `${Invoice_No_Actual}` + `.pdf`);
               res.contentType("application/pdf");

  res.send(`data:application/pdf;base64,${new Buffer.from(data).toString("base64")}`);
     }
   });
```

2. **Front end** snippet of code

```
         
        console.log("content", content);// this content if i convert online tool it does shows the correct PDF file 
        
    
        const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "application/pdf" });
        console.log(blob);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
      };
```

```
     const generatePdf = (invoice_Name) => {
        let invoice_Object = {
          invoice_Name: invoice_Name,
        };

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("content-type", "application/json");
    headers.append("responseType", "blob");
    // headers.append("responseType", "blob");
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(invoice_Object),
    };
    const newRequest = new Request("http://localhost:5000/api/invoice-only", options);

    (async () => {
      const invoice_Call = await fetch(newRequest)
        .then((res) => {
           
          return res.text();  
          
        })
        .then((data) => {
          
          generateFile(data, invoice_Name);
        });
    })();
  };
```

3. **Frontend code** that triggers the `API call`

```
     let invoice_Name = `${users_user_id}` + `_` + `${invoiceNo}`; 
// to get the specific invoice (userid_invoiceNO) usefull to get specific file from backend
        <span role="button" tabIndex="-1" onKeyDown={() => generatePdf(invoice_Name)} onClick={() => generatePdf(invoice_Name)}>invoiceNo:{invoiceNo}
         </span>
```

4. when doing the console i get the following
   `console.log("resxx", res)`
   [image]
   `console.log("textxx", data);` 
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending the above file through your API as an attachment then you want to use a [javascript blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to read the file since it's non-native.

```js
const generateFile = (content, fileName) => {
  const blob = new Blob([content]);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = fileName;
  link.click();
}

const generatePdf = () => {
  (...some api request here)
    .then(res => {
        ...catching the response here
        const filename = 'new_file.pdf'; // You can get this name from the API
        generateFile(res, filename))
    .catch(.....)
}

return (
  <span
      role="button"
      tabIndex="-1"
      onKeyDown={generatePdf}
      onClick={generatePdf}
    >
     Download PDF
    </span>
)
```

Here we are creating a new Blob from the content sent through the API and then triggering a download popup to show up in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry i am a bit new with all this.  where i will use the above function is it inside the  <a href="#" download {.....} or outside the main  return (...) or call  it from inside download{...} as i understand the download will make the file downloadable when clicked on <a> tags

Comment: @Umair_007 I updated the question to add a complete example along with the render function and the function with the api call. Let me if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks again , i had few issues setting the backend to send the file but now it seems like it is sending the file but still i am unable to open the pdf, i have updated the code above. i have tried to implement as you advised but not sure what exactly i am missing now.

Comment: the additional thing  i added was const text1 = res.text(); as otherwise it was asking to be resolved, unless i can use something else to resolve it.

Comment: @Umair_007 do you mean that you were able to successfully download the pdf but it won't open or that the popup for download never shows up?

Comment: On your API side, what is the content disposition?

Comment: As soon as i click the invoice number it opens the PDF but its all blank white, but on the server side folder if i go inside i can see the correct PDF exists.

Comment: i think saying  API side you mean on the server side. i wasnt using contenet disposition as i wasn't sure about it, but i have now set it  updated in the above code as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218926/discussion-between-umair-007-and-anonn023432).

Comment: I have also uploaded the base64 code that i am getting when console logging at pastebin, https://pastebin.com/W4zEXyPy

and when using online converting tool i found this code generating correct PDF